# How do I fetch a number from a specific position in a table?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first time trying panda and I can not understand any of the documentation or other similar questions. I am trying to fetch data from the live market.

imports here:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import datetime
```

then the base code:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-04')
end = pd.to_datetime('today')
tesla_df = data.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start , end)
print(tesla_df)
```

[image: this is the output]

sorry if this has been done to death but i'm just really confused on how to get a specific value (e.g. the Close column for the most recent date)

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 5 most recent dates:

```
tesla_df.sort_index()['Close'].tail(5)
```

If you want the latest date:

```
tesla_df.sort_index()['Close'].tail(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try Using The "iloc" Command To Fetch a Specific Row

```
import pandas as pd #Try this for importing
#Create a Dataframe like this
data = {'1' : ['s', 'h', 'e'],  
        '2' : ['e', 'p', 's'], 
        '3' : ['a', 'r', 'e'],
        '4' : ['k', 'i', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print("This is The Original dataframe") 
display(df)

print("Fetching Row 1 ")
display(df.iloc[1])
```

I Hope This Works For You, Also please explain your question more deeply, I couldn't quite figure out what you meant.